# Compiling OpenCV errors

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, compilation, raspberry-pi

I trying to install opencv on my raspberry pi 3b+. Iam basing on tutorial from [pyimagesearch](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/18/install-guide-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-jessie-opencv-3/).Iam on **Step #5: Compile and Install OpenCV**. I got errors after I execute **make** command. On 15% I got errors like on the [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YeKw.png).

Errors:

```
[ 22%] Building CXX object modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_dnn.dir/src/layers/fully_connected_layer.cpp.o
/home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In member function ‘bool OutputMediaStream_FFMPEG::open(const char*, int, int, double)’:
/home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:2207:30: warning: ignoring return value of ‘int avformat_write_header(AVFormatContext*, AVDictionary**)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
         avformat_write_header(oc_, NULL);
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/build.make:154: modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4209: modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 22%] Building CXX object modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_dnn.dir/src/layers/im2col.cpp.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_dnn.dir/src/layers/layers_common.cpp.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_dnn.dir/src/layers/lrn_layer.cpp.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_dnn.dir/src/layers/mvn_layer.cpp.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_dnn.dir/src/layers/pooling_layer.cpp.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_dnn.dir/src/layers/reshape_layer.cpp.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_dnn.dir/src/layers/slice_layer.cpp.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_dnn.dir/src/layers/softmax_layer.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_dnn.dir/src/layers/split_layer.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_dnn.dir/src/torch/THDiskFile.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_dnn.dir/src/torch/THFile.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_dnn.dir/src/torch/THGeneral.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_dnn.dir/src/torch/torch_importer.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_dnn.dir/opencl_kernels_dnn.cpp.o
[ 23%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_dnn.so
[ 23%] Built target opencv_dnn
make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2
```

When my cmake looks like:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
      -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
      -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
      -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.1.0/modules \
      -D ENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF \
      -D WITH_TBB=OFF \
      -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

I got errors like:

```
make[2]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/build.make:154: modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4209: modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2
```

I will be greateful for any advice.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Sorry. Errors I got:

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I handled the problem. My solution was to install brand new Raspberry Pi Buster image on sd card. Then I installed opencv basing on another tutorial from [pyimagesearch](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/09/16/install-opencv-4-on-raspberry-pi-4-and-raspbian-buster/).